# SVGの、circle中心に伸びるpathのmarker-endの調整方法

Tags: svg

半径が点の範疇以上に指定されている円があり、Pathをその縁の中心を目的地にしています。
例えば、次のようなSVGを描きました。

```html
<svg width="600px" height="400px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">


<!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
<g>
<defs>
<marker id="endpoint" viewBox="-50 0 50 50" refX="0" refY="25" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20" orient="auto">
  <path d="M -50 0 L 0 25 L -50 50 z"></path>
</marker>
</defs>
<text x="10" y="50">単にmarker-endを指定しても、circleの半径が大きいと円の下敷きになってしまう</text>
<path d="M 0,100 C 50,100 80,131 130,131 C 130,131 180,130 200,100" 
 stroke="black"
 fill="none"
 marker-end="url(#endpoint)"
 > 
 </path>
 </g>
 <g>
 <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="20" stroke-width="2px" stroke="#aaa" fill="#fff" opacity="0.75"></circle>
 <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
 <text x="10" y="240">このように、円の淵に矢印の先端が来るようにしたい。</text>
 <text x="10" y="260">ただし、進入角度は予測できず、線も一本だけとも限らない</text>
<path d="M 0,300 C 50,300 80,331 130,331 C 130,331 180,330 200,300" 
 stroke="black"
 fill="none"
 > 
 </path>
 <path d="M 185 315 L 174 312 L 185 326 z"></path>
 
 <circle cx="200" cy="300" r="20" stroke-width="2px" stroke="#aaa" fill="#fff" opacity="0.75"></circle>
 </g>
 
  <text x="10" y="20">2016/07/03 14:30 本スニペットを追加</text>
 </svg>
```

矢印が円の中に消えてしまうため、 marker内で生成する三角形をrefXで外側に来るようにずらしますが、この方法では、進入角度によっては矢印としての三角形が成り立ちません。
方法が無いかと色々探しているのですが、見当たらない状況です。
何か良い方法は無いでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

(線は複数あり、また予測不能ないろいろな角度から侵入します。)

Comment: 円の淵に矢印が来る様にして、それが常に円の中心を向く様にしたいということですか？

Comment: そうです。https://jsfiddle.net/zjgnfw88/2/ このように円の淵に矢印の先端がくるようにしたいのですが、急な角度で曲がりながら入ってくる事もあり得るため、決めうちでは難しい状態です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本件、色々調べ方法が見つからず、また海外版（本家）のStackOverflowで問い合わせたところ、「No way」手段は無いよ、という回答に至りました。
結果、Javascriptを介入させ、Javascriptによって制御を行う、という形を取りました。

```js
var paths = new Array();
var autonext = -1;
var draw = function(type, opts) {
  var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", type);
  for (var k in opts) {
    svg.setAttribute(k, opts[k]);
  }
  return svg;
};


var getCircleDestination = function(from, to) {

  var tx = parseFloat(to.getAttribute("cx"));
  var ty = parseFloat(to.getAttribute("cy"));

  var fx = from.center.x;
  var fy = from.center.y;

  var w = fx - tx;
  var h = fy - ty;

  var z = Math.sqrt(w * w + h * h);
  var r = parseFloat(to.getAttribute("r"));

  var dz = z / r;

  var dx = tx + w / dz;
  var dy = ty + h / dz;

/* dx2,dy2・・・ここをより改良する必要があります */
  var dx2 = tx + w / (dz * 1.2); 
  var dy2 = ty + h / (dz * 1.2);

  var circle = draw("circle", {
    "cx": dx,
    "cy": dy,
    "r": 3,
    "fill": "red"
  });

  return {
    "s": {
      "x": dx2,
      "y": dy2
    },
    "svg": circle
  };
};

var nextline = function(){
  
  var x = Math.random() * canvas.clientWidth/4;
  var y = Math.random() * canvas.clientHeight;
  if(Math.random() * 100 < 50){x+=canvas.clientWidth/4*3;}
  var from = {
    "center": {
      "x": x,
      "y": y
    }
  };

  var svg = getCircleDestination(from, circle);
  var c = svg.svg;
  var stx = svg.s.x;
  var sty = svg.s.y;

  var ttx = svg.s.x + (Math.random() * 10 + 15) * (svg.s.x < x ? 1 : -1);
  var tty = svg.s.y + (Math.random() * 10 + 15) * (svg.s.y < y ? 1 : -1);

  var p = draw("path", {
    "d": "M" + x + "," + y + " Q " + ttx + "," + tty + " " + stx + "," + sty + " " + c.getAttribute("cx") + "," + c.getAttribute("cy"),
    "stroke": "black",
    "fill": "none",
    "marker-end": "url(#endpoint)"
  });


  canvas.appendChild(c);
  canvas.appendChild(p);
  paths.push({
    "c": c,
    "p": p
  });
  if (paths.length > 10) {
    var t = paths.shift();
    t.c.remove();
    t.p.remove();
  }
}




var canvas = draw("svg", {
  "width": "400",
  "height": "150",
  "style": "background-color:#f0f0f0;border:1px solid black;"
});
var def = draw("defs", {});
var marker = draw("marker", {
  "id": "endpoint",
  "viewBox": "-50 0 50 50",
  "refX": 0,
  "refY": 25,
  "markerUnits": "strokeWidth",
  "markerWidth": 10,
  "markerHeight": 10,
  "orient": "auto"
});
var marker_path = draw("path", {
  "d": "M -50 0 L 0 25 L -50 50 z"
});
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.style.display = "block";
btn.innerHTML = "Add Line";

canvas.appendChild(def);
canvas.appendChild(marker);
marker.appendChild(marker_path);

document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(canvas);
document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(btn);

var circle = draw("circle", {
  "cx": 200,
  "cy": 75,
  "r": 10,
  "fill": "white",
  "stroke": "black",
  "stroke-width": 1,
  "opacity": 0.5
});
canvas.appendChild(circle);


btn.addEventListener("click", function() { nextline(); });
btn.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){if(autonext == -1){btn.innerHTML = 'Right Click to Interval';}else{btn.innerHTML = 'Right Click to Stop Interval';}});
btn.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){btn.innerHTML = 'Add Line';});
btn.addEventListener("contextmenu", function() {
  if(autonext == -1){
    autonext = setInterval(function(){nextline();},500);
  }else{
    clearTimeout(autonext);
    autonext = -1;
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

ご考慮いただきました皆様、有難う御座いました。

Answer (score -1):

svg に詳しいわけではありませんが以下の本家SOでの以下のQAが参考になりそうに思います。

[Arrow triangles on my SVG line - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11809868/5120044) より抜粋

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-50 -100 200 200">
<defs>
  <marker id='mid' orient="auto"
    markerWidth='2' markerHeight='4'
    refX='0.1' refY='1'>
    <!-- triangle pointing right (+x) -->
    <path d='M0,0 V2 L1,1 Z' fill="orange"/>
  </marker>
  <marker id='head' orient="auto"
    markerWidth='2' markerHeight='4'
    refX='0.1' refY='2'>
    <!-- triangle pointing right (+x) -->
    <path d='M0,0 V4 L2,2 Z' fill="red"/>
  </marker>
</defs>

<path
  id='arrow-line'
  marker-mid='url(#mid)'
  marker-end='url(#head)'
  stroke-width='5'
  fill='none' stroke='black'  
  d='M0,0 L20,20 C40,40 40,40 60,20 L80,0'
  />

</svg>
```

要は `orient="auto"` が肝のようです。